# How to search for irregular signals: Fourier, DWT or k-means?

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-means, signal-processing, fourier-transform

**See my notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QF59winaqYt6HjhtbvU4j9DdJXaC1_VX#scrollTo=SLT-ileLvlUa)**

I want to search for irregular time signals in a data set of ~3 500 000 time signals. I can't give a clear definition of irregular signal, but it must fulfil the criteria of: not being flat, exhibiting a "dip" or a "jump" larger than 2% of the average signal and this feature should not be periodic or oscillating. By eyeballing I have found hundreds of flat and oscillating signals, but just a few that are irregular (see fig. 1). There are 1000-5000 data points/signal, although sometimes data points are missing or there is even a large gap.

My first plan for designing the search for irregular signals was:

1. Apply Fourier transformation (DFT, FFT o.s.) on all the signals $f(t)$ to get $f(t)=A \cdot \Sigma_k^n e^{ikx} \hat{f}_k$
2. Afterwards, approximate by setting the smallest contributions $\hat{f}_k$ to 0
3. Then, calculate PCA on the 3 500 000 sets of $[\hat{f}_1, \hat{f}_2, ... \hat{f}_n]$
4. there should be only "orthogonal" contributions left, on them I can perform K-means clustering

   - or calculate the neighbours to the irregular signals $f_i(t)$ I have already found by the affinity $|f_i(t)-f(t)|=[ (\hat{f}_{i1} - \hat{f}_{1})^2 + (\hat{f}_{i2} - \hat{f}_{2})^2 + ... + (\hat{f}_{in} - \hat{f}_{n})^2 ]^{1/n}$

Steps 1. and 2. above gave really good results in python by using `numpy.fft`. Even when I set 98% of the smallest $\hat{f}_k$ to 0 (fig. 2 and 3) the back transformation of the irregular signal into the time domain was very well approximated (fig. 4). But I figured out, that K-means and $|f_i(t)-f(t)|$ might not help me in finding more irregular signals, because they might be not concentrated like the flat or oscillating ones (fig. 5). And I also just learned about DTW (Dynamic Time Warping), that in some cases helps to identify similarity of signals.

**My questions are**: Is using `numpy.fft` a legitimate method or will the gaps in the data compromise the results? Is there a better similarity measure than $|f_i(t)-f(t)|$ I presented above?

I am new to FFT, k-means and DWT, so explicit answers are appreciated!

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

[image: fig3]

[image: fig4]

[image: fig5]

Comment: Could you provide a clear characterization of what an "irregular signal" is?  The illustration, which is nice, nevertheless is ambiguous, because it admits many reasonable but different interpretations.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I included a definition in the second sentence on my question. Does it help? I can't give a better definition, unfortunately, because I don't know myself what to expect

Comment: Thank you.  Your criteria are clearer--but I still find it difficult to reconcile them either with (a) the graphics at the end, which don't seem to accord with those criteria or (b) any of your proposed methodology, none of which seems adapted to those criteria.